# Get position of substring after a specific position in Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a table like this:

```
+-----+-----------------------+
| id  |                 word  |
+---+-------------------------+
|  1  |  today is a nice day  |
|  2  |          hello world  |
|  3  |           he is good  |
|  4  |       is it raining?  |
+-----+-----------------------+
```

I want to get the position of a substring (`is`) in the `word` column only if it occurs after the 3rd position

```
+-----+-----------------------+-----------------+
| id  |                 word  |  substr_position|
+---+-------------------------+-----------------+
|  1  |  today is a nice day  |              7  |
|  2  |          hello world  |              0  |
|  3  |           he is good  |              4  |
|  4  |       is it raining?  |              0  |
+-----+-----------------------+-----------------+
```

Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [locate](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/functions.html#locate) function in spark. 
It returns the first occurrence of a substring in a string column, after a specific position.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import locate, col
df.withColumn("substr_position", locate("is", col("word"), pos=3)).show()

+---+-------------------+---------------+
| id|               word|substr_position|
+---+-------------------+---------------+
|  1|today is a nice day|              7|
|  2|        hello world|              0|
|  3|         he is good|              4|
|  4|     is it raining?|              0|
+---+-------------------+---------------+
```